# What is the drawback if I do not invoke the UdpClient.Close() method?

Tags: c#, .net, udpclient

I have the following code block, and it affects my program efficiency. The problem here is if the target host exists, everything is OK. But if it does exist, it takes too long to execute. Finally, I found out the "udp.Close()" occupies the most of execution time. If I does not invoke the close method, the efficiency is good.

Can anyone help me tell me what is the drawback if I do not invoke the close method?? Thank you very much.

```
{ // This is my code block, I need to execute it many many times.
string ipAddress = Dns.GetHostAddresses("joe-pc").FirstOrDefault().ToString();
UdpClient udp = new UdpClient(ipAddress, Port);
udp.Send(msg, msg.Length);
udp.Close();
udp = null;
}
```

Comment: Side note - why are you setting it to `null` afterwards?

Comment: From my personal experience, it is required to set udp = null; at the end after udp.Close(). I checked the retained instances using memory profiler (dotmemory) and found that the UdpClient instances still remain unless udp = null; is used.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The drawback is that you'll have a resource leak. You *may* be lucky enough that garbage collection happens often enough that it doesn't demonstrate itself in your program, but why take the chance? From the documentation on [`Close`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.sockets.udpclient.close.aspx):

> The **Close** disables the underlying [`Socket`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.sockets.socket.aspx) and releases all managed and unmanaged resources associated with the [`UdpClient`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.sockets.udpclient.aspx).

Note, it talks of unmanaged resources. These will *only* be released by the `UdpClient` running some code - it either does it in `Close`/`Dispose`, or it has to do it in its `Finalize` method - nothing else will cause them to be released (assuming the program stays running).

You *may* be able to hide the cost of the `Close` operation by using `Task.Run` to have it run on another thread - but you'd have to weigh up the cost of doing so.

---

Or, to put it in more concrete terms - you say that you need this method to run many times. By not cleaning up your resources here, you would increase the chances that a subsequent call will fail completely because it cannot *acquire* the required resources (they're all tied up in existing, non-`Close`d `UdpClient` instances).

---

And, as indicated in my comment, the following line is pointless:

```
udp = null;
```

Such code used to be of use in COM era VB, but it has no place in the .NET world.

Answer (score 1):

The `Close()` disables the underlying Socket and releases all managed and unmanaged resources associated with the UdpClient.
if u not closed then it doesn't disables & deallocate resources like ur port & ipaddress

Answer (score 0):

Instead of Using `Send` could you use `BeginSend` and then in your callback handle an exception when you attempt to Close if that is actually the problem?

Answer (score 0):

You're targeting joe-pc presumably with different ip addresses as the dns record changes, but you reuse the same UdpClient for each send.  Just remember to Close() it when you're all done.

Use

```
//
// Summary:
//     Sends a UDP datagram to a specified port on a specified remote host.
//
// Parameters:
//   dgram:
//     An array of type System.Byte that specifies the UDP datagram that you intend
//     to send represented as an array of bytes.
//
//   bytes:
//     The number of bytes in the datagram.
//
//   hostname:
//     The name of the remote host to which you intend to send the datagram.
//
//   port:
//     The remote port number with which you intend to communicate.
//
// Returns:
//     The number of bytes sent.
//
public int Send(byte[] dgram, int bytes, string hostname, int port);
```

and skip the dns lookup too.

Answer (score 0):

I know this is a while but I stumbled today upon this question and wanted to add:

udp=null;

is not pointless imho. You can see in some cases in a memory profiler that your instance is still available if you dont set it to null.

Comment: I also noticed it. udp.Close() is not removing the instance from the heap. Need to add udp=null; after udp.Close() to remove the instances.

Comment: It's a local variable going out of scope, right? That's hard to believe, but two people say they saw it. I wonder if it eventually would get released.